# How do I keep ships repaired in the field in Endless Space?

Tags: endless-space

I have repair modules on some of my ships but that only seems to be a combat thing. How do you repair ships? Do they do it automatically or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [FAQ thread in the official forum](http://forums.amplitude-studios.com/showthread.php?1546-Endless-Space-FAQ):

> **How do I repair damaged ships?**
>
> Ship repair themselves a certain percentage each turn they are
>   in a friendly system, Hero Abilities and Battle Actions can also be
>   used to repair. Installed ship repair modules do repairs both in
>   combat and on the Galaxy Map. Specific tech can increase ship repair
>   rate.

They do repair themselves extremely slowly outside of battle, as far as I have observed. I tend to use the repair nano bot card during battle a lot to help keep my fleets at full health.

Comment: You do? Thank for the tip, I'll be sure to focus on countering that card if I even play against you. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Ships repair themselves each turn - there are different modificators on repair:

- own system means highest repair rate
- repair technology provides fleet repair per turn (galaxy map)
- repair technology provides ship and/or fleet repair per combat cycle
- outside of combat repair techniques even work on different fleets. Meaning: You could have a fleet of fast repair/support ships in a different fleet and warp 'em in after your fight ;)

Comment: Wow, healing effects can be system-wide? Neat!